# How to modify an image dynamically

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm trying to modify my bitmap to change their pixels to a random color. This is the way I do it (I'm using the **FlashPunk** library):

```
private var _v:Point = new Point;
private var _speed:Point = new Point(200, 200);
private var _bmpData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(24, 24, false, 0x000000)
private var _bmpImage:Image = new Image(_bmpData);

public function Player(p:Point) 
{
    graphic = _bmpImage;
    x = p.x;
    y = p.y;
}

override public function update():void
{
    updateMovement();
    updateCollision();

    super.update();
}

override public function render():void 
{
    _bmpData.lock();
    for (var j:int = 0; j < _bmpData.height; j++) {
        for (var i:int = 0; i < _bmpData.width; i++) {
            _bmpData.setPixel(i, j, FP.rand(0xffffff));
        }
    }
    _bmpData.unlock();

    graphic = new Image(_bmpData);
    super.render();
}
```

So ok, the function that does this is render(), but in the line

```
graphic = new Image(_bmpData);
```

I get new memory for graphic, and this translate into a memory leak in the game. Here is an image of this: 
[image]
And as you can see, the MEM: part is constantly increasing :/

Anyone knows another way to do this?

Comment: Why can't you just `free` `graphic` before calling `new Image`?

Comment: If I put delete(graphic); brefore the new Image() I get the next error: Error: Attempt to delete the fixed property graphic.  Only dynamically defined properties can be deleted.
delete(graphic); I'm new at AS3 so for sure this'll be a trivial question but I don't find the answer :/

Comment: Can't you just set `graphic.bitmapData` to the changed value instead of using `new Image()` every time?

Comment: I can't, there is no way to assign a bitmap data without reserve memory I think...

Comment: If you stick a call to `System.gc()` after setting `graphic`, does the memory still go up?

Comment: Okay, so at the end with only a call to _bmpImage.updateBuffer(); it works. I update the main post.

Comment: In this case you should post your own answer and valid it so people who have the same problem could read a resolved question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I only had to replace

`graphic = new Image(_bmpData);`

for

`_bmpImage.updateBuffer();` and now it works fine :)

[Here is the doc for that function](http://flashpunk.net/docs/net/flashpunk/graphics/Image.html#updateBuffer%28%29)
Cheers!